# Ubuntu 22.04 Not Recognizing Sata SSD

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, usb-installation

Edit 3: I am using a Dell Inspiron 5567 with latest bios
When I boot Ubuntu from a USB Stick,
In the install menu, It only shows the USBB Stick to install onto.

Edit 4: I have Fast Startup Disabled

I have done the following already

- Set Sata Mode To AHCI
- Booted In UEFI

Any help?

Edits. My Gparted window:

[image]

lsblk:

[image]

Comment: If you run "Try Ubuntu" (as you Boot the USB stick); does the SSD appear when you run e.g. `$ lsblk -p`, `gnome-disks` or `gparted`? What does these say about the SSD and it's partitioning?

Comment: Boot from the USB. Use the try Ubuntu option. Open gparted. Select the internal drive from the drop down menu on top right corner. Take a screenshot of the gparted app window. Add the screenshot to your question by [editing your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1416922/edit).

Comment: Is there Windows on the internal drive? Is Fast Startup activated in Windows (this is the default)? In that case you should turn it off in order for the data to be saved correctly and completely, so that Ubuntu's Linux tools can see it. -- If that is not the problem, please check if some other tool can see it: Boot live "Try Ubuntu" from the Ubuntu USB drive, and in a terminal window run `lsblk` or in order to get more details `lsblk -o name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint,model`; one single command line

Comment: It looks like your Windows has **Fast Startup** enabled. You have to disable it from within Windows. See [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) for more.